# lost /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-terminal

I somehow lost `/etc/sources.list`
I'm tired of googling it all day. Please help me :(

And it is giving me this warning.

```
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

The program 'screenfetch' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install screenfetch
You will have to enable the component called 'universe'
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

A: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

A: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

A: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

A: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

A: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

B: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

A: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

C: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

D: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

D: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

D: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

C: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

C: command not found
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'

C: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked something similar on G+ some time ago. Cannot give you the answer directly because I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links:

https://plus.google.com/100718986567621730640/posts/Pgh3YhkWErW

**EDIT**

with more reputation now, the full answer:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/patches.list        
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial main
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The problem was that the sources.list contains a lot of links and I didn't have the reputation to add more than 2 in one post. So I decided to give a suboptimal answer, than none.

Comment: Oh, I understand. No problem. Just remember to update your answer once you have the rep.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` from elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki follow.

```
#deb cdrom:[elementary OS 0.4.1 _Loki_ - Stable amd64 (20170517)]/ xenial contrib main non-free

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to  
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```